# sequalize - create model from plain object using generic type

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have a situation where I need to convert plain object to sequalize model dynamically and generically.

```
saveSomethingGeneric<T>(plainObject){
    plainObject.save();// this is not possible
}

saveSomethingGeneric<UserModel>({fullName, address});
```

how can I convert the `plainObject` to a model and save it by the Generic type?
in type orm, they have something
`getRepositor<T>().create({fullName, address})`

Whats the equivalent in sequalize?

**UPDATE**
When using `Model.build` there is an error.
Also, how sequalize knows the type/table? Model.build does not request any hint about the table...
`Model.build({name: 'test'})` can be Car Person and whatever.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `Model.build(obj, options)` method to generate an Instance from a plain object.

If you want to persist it to the database you can call `await instance.save()`.

If the object represents a record that already exists in the database set `options.isNewRecord: false`. This makes more sense, for example loading the data from a difference source that you know already exists, and have the primary key in `obj`.

```js
// create a new instance of a model that is not persisted to the db
const instance = Model.build(obj, {
  // isNewRecord: false,
});
// save to the db
await instance.save();
```

You can do this more directly if you want to create a new record with:

```js
const instance = await Model.create(obj);
```

Note that the above may not contain the primary key in some cases.

Comment: @SexyMF sorry if that wasn't clear, in this case `Model` is the model that you defined for the table using `sequelize.define()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. but im looking for a dynamic way to do that. something like `sequelize.buid('SomeModel', {name: 'test'})`

Comment: `sequelize.models['SomeModel'].build({name: 'test'});`

Comment: BTW, I just found out that `sequelize.models` is not available in typescript. any alternative? thamls

Comment: @SexyMF I'm not using Typescript but I have a `./models/index.js` loader that defines all the models in folder and returns an object which has a property for each model.